# How to model data for a JSON API and a Document Database

Tags: json, rest, haskell, nosql

I am making a simple REST API in front of a NoSQL database that stores records as documents similar to JSON (but not exactly the same). Each record has some fields, including `id` for the database, and also including some derived fields, like `dateCreated`.

Any time I GET anything, I want to return the objects with all the fields.

```
// GET /users returns an array of these in JSON
// [{id:"xxx", name:"Bobby", dateCreated:"YYYY-MM-DD"]
data User = User { id :: String, name :: String, dateCreated :: XXX }
```

But any time I POST or PUT anything, they client should send an object with the `id` field and any derived fields missing. The database is responsible to create the id when I save it, and I would create some derived fields

```
// POST /users would need you to post only the name.
// {name:"Henry"} 
data PartialUser = PartialUser { name :: String }
```

If resource represents objects of type `User`, what should I call the thing client is sending to me? Would you make all the derived fields `Maybe` values? Or would you create a second object called `PostedUser` or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be many things:

- a request body
- the representation of the intended resource state of the client
- a command DTO which you can send to the domain logic in order to process it by CQRS

I would make it CreateUser command, but if you don't want to use CQRS and DDD, then you would probably call it as PartialUserRepresentation, or you don't create a data structure, just use the properties to create a new User entity. Ofc. if you use entities.

So I would say it depends on the architecture of your system.